# InsertAfter after page loaded

Tags: jquery

I want run script last :

```
<script>
  $('ul#portfolio-list').insertAfter('ul#portfolio-filter');
 </script>
```

It means after all pages are loaded completely, then that script is actual for running..

Comment: wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() {...});`

Comment: or, if you don't want to use jquery, put it at the bottom of your page. That is how html5bp does it.

Comment: @ElGavilan: You mean I should use Javascript instead of?

Comment: Either way works. Some people prefer to do it that way for performance reasons. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

do it like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('ul#portfolio-list').insertAfter('ul#portfolio-filter');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I wrapped it in but it did not run. :).